# How to count equals string in String sort array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to count the same words in my `String` array and print those counts as an integer array. For example:

input:  `String [] s = {"be", "be", "to", "onto", "onto", "onto"}`

> output 2,1,3

input: `String words[] = {"be", "be", "not", "or", "to", "to", "to"}`

> output : 2,1,1,3

My code:

```
    //O(n)
    public static int [] MaxNumber(String [] arr)
    {
        int [] Number_arr=new int[11];
        int count=1;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
                count++;
            else{
                Number_arr[j]=count;
                j++;
                count=1;
            }

        }

        return Number_arr;
    }
```

My input: `String [] Sarr= {"be", "be", "not", "not", "not", "or", "to", "to", "to"};`

> My output is wrong: 2,3,1
>
> correct output is: 2,3,1,3

How can I do that?

Comment: Your code counts consecutive equals words. Doesn't count duplicate words non consecutive in the array. Is that what you like to search? As an example consider the array {"duplicate", "other", "duplicate"}

Comment: can you check your correct output again ?? after 2,3 you want to print 1 or 2 ??

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add the count of the last sequence of equal Strings :

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
        count++;
    else{
        Number_arr[j]=count;
        j++;
        count=1;
    }

}
Number_arr[j]=count; // added
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int [] MaxNumber(String [] arr)
    {
        int [] Number_arr=new int[11];
        int count=1;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
                count++;
            else{
                Number_arr[j]=count;
                j++;
                count=1;
            }

        }

        Number_arr[j]=count;   // *added line*
        for (int i = 0; i < Number_arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(Number_arr[i]+"  ");
        }

        return Number_arr;
    }
```

It seems the last occurance are not added properly. Look at the extra added line.

Answer (score 1):

Your given input is:

```
    String [] Sarr= {"be" , "be", "not","not","not", "or","to","to","to"};
```

You can see the value of `Sarr[6]`, `Sarr[7]` and `Sarr[8]` are the same. Assume the following values:

```
    i = 6; j = 3; count = 1;
```

Now debug your code, you will notice:

```
    i = 7; j = 3; count = 2;
    i = 8; j = 3; count = 3;
```

At this point where `i = 8` the test condition `i<arr.length-1;` returns false for the next iteration hence the latest value of count will never be added to the `Number_arr` because the `if-else` part will not execute. Put the following statement at the end of for-loop to ensure that the last value of count is also added to the `Number_arr`

```
    Number_arr[j]=count;
```

The modified code is:

```
    public static int [] MaxNumber(String [] arr)
    {
            int [] Number_arr=new int[11];
            int count=1;
            int j=0;
            int k=0;
            for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
                    count++;
                else
                {
                    Number_arr[j]=count;
                    j++;
                    count=1;
                }
            }
            Number_arr[j]=count;
            return Number_arr;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int [] MaxNumber(String [] arr)
{
String [] arr={"be" , "be" , "to" , "onto","onto","onto"};
int [] Number_arr=new int[11];
int count=1;
int j=0;
int k=0;
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
        count++;
    else{
        Number_arr[++j]=count;
        count=1;
    }
}
Number_arr[++j]=count;
return Number_arr;
}
```

I have added one line of code....tried to keep your code as it is...
i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You've got answers that solve the situation where you're dealing with an array that has consecutive duplicate words.  However, will the words in your array always be consecutive? If not, you may want to rethink you're logic.

Having said that, using streams from Java 8 made this rather trivial.  Might not be O(n), but it gets the job done.  We get each distinct word from the array and then do a filter count on them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String [] Sarr= {"be", "be", "not", "not", "not", "or", "to", "to", "to", "be", "not"};
    Arrays.stream(Sarr).distinct()
            .forEach(word -> System.out.println(word + ": " + Arrays.stream(Sarr).filter(w -> w.equals(word)).count()));
}
```

Results:

```
be: 3
not: 4
or: 1
to: 3
```

If you're wanting to store the count results into an array, then try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String [] Sarr= {"be", "be", "not", "not", "not", "or", "to", "to", "to", "be", "not"};
    String[] distincts = Arrays.stream(Sarr).distinct().toArray(size -> new String[size]);

    long[] wordCount = new long[distincts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount.length; i++) {
        final String distinct = distincts[i];
        wordCount[i] = Arrays.stream(Sarr).filter(word -> word.equals(distinct)).count();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordCount));
}
```

Results:

```
[3, 4, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another simple solution with Java-Stream-API would be:

```
    Stream<String> stream= Stream.of("a","a","b","c","c");
    Map<String, Long> counter = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::new, Collectors.counting()));
    for (Entry<String, Long> count: counter.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(count.getKey() + " : " + count.getValue());
    }
```

Result:

```
a : 2
b : 1
c : 2
```